# How to delay proximityAlert setting off?

Tags: android, location, proximity

Bit of a dumb question, I have successfully created a mapactivity that lets users place a proximityalert  at their current coordinates by clicking the map.
How do I prevent the proximitylert from setting off, given that they will be in the proximity alert area by default? I understand there is a key for entering and exiting, does the system recognize that I am by default, exiting?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is not to try.  Instead, ignore an incoming proximity alert if it comes too soon after being set (you can save the time it was set in shared preference or similar storage).

Comment: Interesting. I can also use the booleans for entering and exiting right? If it prox alert spawns on the user, does it count as being entered?